# $\pi_1(S)$ and $H_*(S)$ of a surface with disks attached

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fundamental-groups

Let $S$ be the closed orientable surface surface given in the picture below, where we attach three disks $D^2$ to $S$: the first along $a$ via a degree $2$ map, the second along $b$ via a degree $3$ map, and at $c$ via a degree $4$ map. Compute $\pi_1(S)$ and $H_*(S)$.

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

I don't see why the disks should change $\pi_1(S)$ from the ordinary surface $M_g$ so this can be computed the ordinary way. As for $H_*(S)$, clearly $H_0(S)=\mathbb{Z}$ since the space is path connected. I would think $H_n(S)=0$ for $n>2$. It is now a matter of computing $H_1(S)$ and $H_2(S)$. I think I should be able to 'ignore' the disk attached at $c$ because $S$ deformation retracts to $S$ without the disk attached at $c$ (correct?). But figuring out how to deal with the rest of the space is stumping me.

Do I just break the space into the $3$ pieces using Mayer-Vietoris and compute the homology of the $3$ pieces and then piece together? I would think any of the 'legs' can be deformed down to just a wedge of two circles and the disk is attached to one of these circles with the given degrees. Is this correct?

Comment: I think the disk attached along $a$ _does_ change $\pi_1(S)$. Notice that $2a$ is a non-trivial loop in $S$ - but when you attach a disk along $a$ via a degree $2$ map, you can slide this loop into the interior of the disk and contract it to a point. The standard way to compute $\pi_1(S)$ is to use Seifert-van-Kampen, and for $H_\star(S)$, you would use Mayer-Vietoris. By the way, the disk attached at $c$ may be important - perhaps it creates a new non-trivial $2$-cycle? Why not use Mayer-Vietoris to find out?

Comment: Let me rewrite your question to make a simpler question which may reveal the error: "Let $X$ be the circle $C$ where we attach one disc $D^2$ to $C$ via a degree $1$ map."

Then let me use the logic which you wrote: " I don't see why the discs should change $\pi_1(X)$ from the ordinary circle $C$ so this can be computed in the ordinary way." With this logic, it would follow that $\pi_1(X) \approx \pi_1(C) \approx \mathbb{Z}$. However, $X$ is homeomorphic to $D^2$ which has trivial fundamental group. So attaching discs *can* change the fundamental group.